# how to write a Treemap as a csv

Tags: java, csv, data-structures, treemap

Currently I am having a tree map which is like

```
    TreeMap<String, String> tree_map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

I then add key and value pairs for the Treemap and now I want to write them in a csv by order and line by line (each key value pair).So I tried with

```
ArrayList <String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
     for ( String key :tree_map.keySet() ) {

                list.add(key+","+tree_map.get(key).toString());

                  }    

                BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\"));

                for (String element : list) {
                    br.write(element);
                }
                br.close();
```

But I encountered two problems:

1. It does not print in order.
2. I want to print each key ,value pair
   line by line

Any help  is appreciated.

Comment: From doc: The set's iterator returns the keys in ascending order. Then it should be in the right ordering. What is `grid_list` ??? You should write `list`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used opencsv library and this apparently made the trick.Hope it helps anyone.

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\map.csv")) ;
            for(String keys:tree_map.keySet()){
                String[] y=new String[2];
                y[0]=keys;
                y[1]=tree_map.get(keys).toString();
                writer.writeNext(y);
            }
```